How to use ptrace in order to read/write target process stack?
I'm trying to write a c code which retrieves process A, given by pid, registers and then reads / writes to esp + x where x is any value I want.
The code snippet is:
struct user_regs_struct regs;
waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, (void*)(regs.esp), 200);

Where 200 is arbitrary data.
Invoking strerror(errno) will result in

Input/Output error.

What am I doing wrong?
I've also tried to write with PTRACE_POKEUSER.
I've also ran the command echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope from the shell.

Your target process is running in 32-bit mode, that's why you used ESP not RSP?

Yes. The os is Ubuntu 32-bit.
